D&D is not a physics simulation update
I have this question: Is there a citation for "D&D is not a physics simulation"?, with great answers, for D&D 5e (during the 2014 era).
We now have a fully official statement on it for 2024 5e (from the free rules):

Rules Aren’t Physics. The rules of the game are meant to provide a fun game experience, not to describe the laws of physics in the worlds of D&D, let alone the real world. Don’t let players argue that a bucket brigade of ordinary people can accelerate a spear to light speed by all using the Ready action to pass the spear to the next person in line. The Ready action facilitates heroic action; it doesn’t define the physical limitations of what can happen in a 6-second combat round.

However, this cannot be an answer to a question tagged dnd-5e-2014. What is the right way to update this? Change the tag on the original question to add dnd-5e-2024, and answer it there, or pose an entirely new question? I suspect it is "new question", especially because there are a lot of great answers on that question that only exist because there was no such thing to directly quote back then.

The D&D 5e 2024 Guidance FAQ directly addresses this question:

Can we update answers to dnd-5e-2014 questions with information from the new edition?
No. We are viewing D&D 2024 as a new edition, and just as 5e 2014 answers don't belong on AD&D 2e questions, we ask that you avoid updating old questions tagged dnd-5e-2014 with information from the new edition.
But wait, I have the same exact question for 5e 2024 that was already asked for 5e 2014, what do? Post a new question! New edition, new question. Your 5e 2024 question will not be closed as a duplicate of a similar 5e 2014 question.


Adding a comment to the 2014 question with “Related: same question in the 2024 rules” may well be warranted.

Although the value of opening a question you already know the answer to and is clearly answered in the rules is questionable; I would tend to “shows no effort” and downvote.
